# Chirpy LESS choking on "filter" css property, other misc errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dotless, chirpy

I recently installed Chirpy v2.01 for Visual Studio 2010 and am very excited about the features it offers. I'm running into some issues in the LESS domain, however.

As a first step, I copied over my existing .css file to a new LESS file. I immediately am getting two errors. The first is due to a CSS "filter" property that I have set:

```
div.someClass {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#aaaaaa', endColorstr='#000000');
}
```

This apparently is because the filter value is not technically valid css. LESS has a workaround for this, via escaping. Adding a tilde in front of a quoted section tells LESS to keep the value as-is. The following change should resolve the issue:

```
div.someClass {
    filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#aaaaaa', endColorstr='#000000')";
}
```

Upon saving the file, I still receive an error in the visual studio error console along these lines:

> Error 54  Expected '}' on line 2 in file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Projects\Project\Content\test.chirp.less':
>     [1]: body {
>     [2]:     filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#aaaaaa', endColorstr='#000000')";
>          ----^
>     [3]: }    C:\Users\Administrator\Projects\Project\Content\test.chirp.less 2   5   Project

The .css files are never generated so long as this error comes up. I came across [the following site](http://groups.google.com/group/dotless/browse_thread/thread/25f273c7894672f0/e2db5de1f7c1ec87?lnk=gst&q=dot+less+does+not+honor#e2db5de1f7c1ec87) that seems to describe the issue I'm having, but in a more generic DotLess .NET package. I tried adding this package to my project, but it didn't make a difference. It also looks like it relies on the server to handle the .less to .css conversion, instead of the IDE, as chirpy does.

The second error that I constantly receive, though it doesn't seem to actually stop the generation of the .css files, is the following:

> Error 53  Fatal error, cannot continue: null cannot be converted to an object C:\Users\Administrator\Projects\Project\Content\test.css    1   1   Project

I'd really love to use the LESS functionality that Chirpy offers, but until I can figure out why these errors are happening, I'm limited to using it for mash.

Answer (score 1):

you have to understand that Chirpy is simply using dotlesscss internally to transform the less into css.

So any bug in dotless also applies to Chirpy.

We have patched that bug quite recently and a new dotlesscss version is upcoming.. But how long it will take until Chirpy updates to the new version is up to the Chirpy developers..

greetings Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a similar VS extension that compiles less but it uses less.js directly and doesn't depend on dotless.  [Check it out](https://github.com/StevePotter/LessCssForVisualStudio).